# How to display the differing elements in two string arrays in a loop?

Tags: string, matlab, difference, strcmp, set-difference

I have two string arrays - `f` and `g`. I want the program to print the members of `g` that do not exist in `f`.

I have the following code:

```
% <for ... >
  % <get `f` and `g` as inputs>
  ...
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  while x < a
    while y < b
      w = string(f);
      z = string(g);
      tf = strcmp(w,z);
      for tf == 0 %         < < < < < Help needed with this
        fprintf('%s\n',z)
      end
      y = y+1;
    end
    x = x+1;
  end
% end
```

The result I get for `tf` looks like `1 0 0`. What I want is for the `fprintf` to display the entries that correspond to `0`'s in `z` (to display the differing members of `w` and `z`), how do I do that?

Comment: The matlab documentation on [logical indexing](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#d120e1410) would be a very useful read

Comment: thankyou, i will try to look for it

Comment: It is not clear what you want to accomplish. Can you explain a little better?

Comment: so i have two strings, say one of them (x) has (1) on it, and the other (y) has (1.2.3), i want the program to tell me which member of y does not exist on x, which should be 2 and 3. im sorry if the my word choice is not programmer-ish.

Comment: Ok, That helps. Are the contents of the arrays always numbers? or strings?

Comment: they're always strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small code showing how to accomplish that:

```
y = '12';
x = 'hello 123';

% First, check if the content of y is present in x
temp = contains(x, y);
if temp == 1 % x contains y
    disp ('x contains y');
else
   disp ('X does not contain y'); 

end

% Second, replace y characters with nothing.
% Result: Only characters not present in y will remain
% for more information type 'docs strrep'
temp2 =  strrep(x,y,'');
disp (['Characters of x not in y: ' temp2])
```

You will see:

> x contains y
>
> Characters of x not in y:hello 3

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by treating your char arrays as sets, finding the difference between the sets, then printing the missing entries. Below are demonstrations how to do this on the *character* level, and on a *word* level.

```
f = 'this is a char array';
g = 'this is a longer char array';

% character-level difference:
d = setdiff(g,f);
disp(d); % output: "eglno"

% word-level difference:
tf = strsplit(f);
tg = strsplit(g);
d = setdiff(tg,tf);
disp(d); % output: "longer"
```

If your inputs are `"strings"` and not `'char arrays'`, simply wrap them in `char()` before beginning.

See also: [`setdiff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html).